# ( libraries issue )

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I am using Sencha Architect with Extjs 4
and by following the basic example here : http://geoext.org/tutorials/quickstart.html#basic-example

i have to switch included libraries from Ext 3 to Ext 4, so i typed :

```
<script src="extjs-4/ext-all.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="extjs-4/ext.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs-4/resources/css/ext-all.css"></link>
<script src="GeoExt/lib/GeoExt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GeoExt/resources/css/geoext-all-debug.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

the problem is i keep getting errors which i think because missing library. but still can't figure out what it is exactly.

Comment: what errors? ExtJs4 and 3 are very different so some of the code might very well be incompatible.

Comment: i haven't code anything yet just try to make Ext 4 work with GeoExt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geo ext is compatible with extjs 3.x top, so doesn't work with extjs 4.
You should check geo ext 2 sources, which is compatible with extjs 4.
See this link http://geoext.blogspot.ro/2012/05/geoext2-sprint-results.html

Comment: well, i end up here https://github.com/geoext/geoext2 to download the GeoExt 2 library but couldn't find the GeoExt 2 javascript file to use it in my libraries. am i in the right place ?