# As a complement to my previous post

Tags: extjs4

As a complement to my previous post :

[( libraries issue )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309998/extjs-4-with-geoext-libraries-issue)

i can't find a css file for GeoExt 2 here : https://github.com/geoext/geoext2

i just could've find GeoExt javascript in src folder

i really need to use GeoExt 2 so anyone can find me a good source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It said here http://geoext.blogspot.ro/2012/05/geoext2-sprint-results.html that they only released the alpha version, the one that you found on git hub. The alpha version is addressed to developers and testers, with a white box approach ( that's why there is no commpressed js, and it has all files). Normaly only from the beta version is available to the public (one js).

Comment: and that means i will not be able to use GeoExt with Ext 4 so far ? is there any temporary solution ?

Comment: I think you can use the existing sources and just add a loader for them as they do in the tests directory. like Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            disableCaching: false,
            enabled: true,
            paths: {
                GeoExt: '../src/GeoExt'
            }
        });